# OnClick FB.ui not consistently executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I have this script to get users to share my website in return for a coupon code to use in the shop.

I'm sure it was working fine. Now on some pages it wont execute until the page is refreshed.

It may not even be a script issue but I can't work it out.

Any ideas?

Here is my code.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>

<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({
          appId      : 'XXXXXX',
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.5'                                    
        });

        $('#ShareForcouponcode').on('click',function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            FB.ui(
             {
               method: 'feed',
               name: 'XXX',
               link: 'XXX'
             },
             function(response) {
               if (response && response.post_id) {
                 // the download link will be activated
$('#ShareForcouponcode').fadeOut();                
$('#infotext').fadeOut(); 
               $('#couponcode').fadeIn();
               } else {
                 // do nothing or ask the user to share it
               }
             }
            );      
        }); 
    };

});

// Load the SDK
(function(d, s, id){
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Comment: _“I have this script to get users to share my website in return for a coupon code to use in the shop”_ – well then you are violating [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) already; you are __not allowed__ to reward users for sharing in any way.

Comment: Well not quite, it's not working yet!

Comment: Good – then keep it that way.